# Modify a Property on JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have created a Test Plan that has two thread groups. Each thread group has a SOAP/XML-RPC Request Sampler. Thread Group A also has a Regular Expression Extractor that contains:

```
Reference Name : ABC
Regular Expression :<response>([A-Z 0-9]+)</response>
Template: $1$
```

Moreover, Thread Group A has a BeanShellAssertion with

```
Name: Extract value
Script: ${__setProperty(ABC, ${ABC})};
```

What I want to do is modify the ABC variable and then pass it on the SOAP Sampler of the second Thread Group.

So, if ABC equals 1000 (response tag holds an int) I want to get that value divided it by two and then pass it on the second sampler like :

```
<abcValue>${__P(modifiedABC)}</abcValue>
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I have tried preProcessors(on the second thread group) and postProccessors (on the first thread group) but whatever I tried gave me back errors like:

```
ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``String value = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(72295) /2); props.put("modifiedABC", v . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Static method parseInt( int ) not found in class'java.lang.Integer'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your response contains anything other than A-Z, ' ', or 0-9, the regex extractor will fail.  It may be better to set the match group to (.+), so it collects whatever is in the response and use a separate regex assertion to check the contents are what you expect. That way you will get a sample fail when the results are bad, rather than a subsequent fail, when your next sample is badly formed through bad input.
2. In the Thread Group A assertion, you need some "s..

   ${__setProperty("ABC", "${ABC}")}

This sets a property called ABC to the value of variable called ABC, which is what I think you intend.

3. Easy way to divide your value is with __javaScript() function..

   ${__javaScript(${ABC}/2)}

You can use this anywhere in jmeter and it will substitute the value you require.  Make sure you have retrieved the property at the start of Thread Group B, as the variable (ABC) is in different scope.

Answer (score 0):

**Thread Group 1**

Please use 'Beanshell Post Processor' for your request. Add this post processor under the sampler where you extract ABC.

Below link will you give you an idea.
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor

Note that by default everything is String in Jmeter. So you might want to convert it to an Integer before dividing it by 2. You have to add something like this in the Beanshell Post processor.

```
modifiedABC = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(props.get("ABC"))/2);
props.put("modifiedABC",modifiedABC);
```

**Thread Group 2**

Now you want to access the modifiedABC in the second thread group.

Simply access it using

```
${__P(modifiedABC)}
```

Comment: Check the modified answer. Use post processor. Let me know

Comment: Thanks for your time. I get the same error described on my edit.

Comment: The Integer.toString part is extremely important. I was doing props.put("number.of.threads", 5), but when my thread executed, it only ran once as if I didn't set it. This fixed it: props.put("number.of.threads", String.valueOf(4));